# MVC 3 Client Validation works intermittently

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

*update: if you set at least one breakpoint in javascript, validation start to works, but without it does not work*

*update: adding jquery tag as this may be connected to validation plugin*

I have MVC 3 version, `System.Web.Mvc` product version is: `3.0.20105.0` modified on `5th of Jan 2011` - i think that's the latest.

I’ve notice that client validation is not working as it suppose in the application that we are creating, so I’ve made a quick test.

I’ve created basic MVC 3 Application using *Internet Application* template.

**I’ve added Test Controller:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication3.Models;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Sample model = new Sample();

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Sample model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Display");
        }

        public ActionResult Display()
        {
            Sample model = new Sample();
            model.Age = 10;
            model.CardNumber = "1324234";
            model.Email = "somedata@test.com";
            model.Title = "hahah";

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Sample
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(4, 120, ErrorMessage = "Oi! Common!")]
        public short Age { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And 3 views:

**Create:**

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Sample

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }*@

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sample</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNumber)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    @*<fieldset>

        @Html.EditorForModel()

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>    *@           
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Display:**

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Sample

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Display</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Sample</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Title</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Title</div>

    <div class="display-label">Email</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Email</div>

    <div class="display-label">Age</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Age</div>

    <div class="display-label">CardNumber</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.CardNumber</div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

**Index:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")
</p>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Display", "Display")
</p>
```

Everything is default here – *Create Controller*, *AddView from controller action* with model specified with proper scaffold template and using provided layout in sample application.

When I will go to */Test/Create* client validation in most cases works only for `Title` and `Age` fields, after clicking *Create* it works for all fields (create does not goes to server).

However in some cases (after a build) `Title` validation is not working and `Email` is, or `CardNumber` or `Title` and `CardNumber` but `Email` is not. But never all validation is working before clicking *Create*.

I’ve tried creating form with `Html.EditorForModel` as well as enforce client validation just before BeginForm:

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

I’m [providing a source code for this sample on dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6644278/MvcValidationSample.zip) – as maybe our dev env is broken :/ I’ve done tests on IE 8 and Chrome 10 beta.

Just in case, in web config validation scripts are enabled:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

**So my questions are**

Is there a way to ensure that Client validation will work as it supposed to work and not intermittently?

Is this a desired behavior and I'm missing something in configuration/implementation?

*update: if you set at least one breakpoint in javascript, validation start to works, but without it does not work*

*update: adding jquery tag as this may be connected to validation plugin*

Comment: this is happening to me too... any resolution to this??

Answer (score 0):

When unobtrusive validation is used - realtime client-side validation works only after first submit. Before first client-side validation of form is executed (just click submit) the realtime validation of fields not initialized and not working.

Comment: yup, but for some fields realtime validation is working before clicking submit. Sometimes is one field, sometimes almost all fields, but never all.

Comment: downvote because while this is correct, it's not the issue the OP has

Answer (score -1):

Put your script references in the document `<head>`. It's likely that there is a timing issue on when the scripts are executed and the validation is hooked up.

Comment: it helped a bit. It does not work in real time, but if I will play with form for long enough and sometime will do double backspace in text field I'm able to force all text fields to validate. But this still does not solve the issue, as I need to put huge effort as the user to get validation information (too much effort - clicking, tabbing, double backspace, deleting until it will trigger - basically I need to enter the field and add/delete text multiply times to trigger that with scripts in <head>).

Comment: The client validation is based on the jquery validation plugin. That behavior is by design - "Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before he had the chance to actually enter a correct value " - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation. It's working correctly if clicking submit causes validation.

Comment: ok, but why than is working for some fields at the beginning? ie. for Age it always works before submitting and users get the message about validation error. This is a case for the rest of the fields too, but it does not work always for the same set of the fields - sometimes it just works only for Age before submit and sometimes it works for Title and Age before submit. And it works for all of the fields if you will setup a break point in JS for instance FireBug. It shouldn't work like that - if it should not work before submit than it shouldn't - but it works. which is confusing for users

Comment: I have no idea. Good luck with this.